# send back compressed JSON in Restlet/GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gzip, restlet

I am writing a Restlet application on GAE similar as described here:
[First Application](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.2/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html)

I am sending back a JSON represntation of an entity, and this works. But I am so far unsuccessful in sending the response compressed.

I tried to add to request an accept-encoding header with "gzip". but that didn't help. Here is how i tested it:

```
URL url = new URL(address);
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
InputStream openStream = urlConn.getInputStream();
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you also need to specify the User-Agent header to force the compression.  From the docs:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Responses

> If the client sends HTTP headers with the request indicating that the
>   client can accept compressed (gzipped) content, App Engine compresses
>   the response data automatically and attaches the appropriate response
>   headers. It uses both the Accept-Encoding and User-Agent request
>   headers to determine if the client can reliably receive compressed
>   responses. Custom clients can force content to be compressed by
>   specifying both Accept-Encoding and User-Agent headers with a value of
>   "gzip".